# Node JS mysql delete from database with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In my node JS I want to send a query to database to delete a record with under two conditions. One is id of the user and the second one is the name. However When I try to do this I receive an error:

```
 throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^
 TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
```

And here is my code:

```
app.post('/delete',function(req,res){

received = req.body;
toDelete = {
    name: received.name,
    id: received.id
}

connection.query("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE User_ID = ? AND NAME = ?", toDelete.id, 
toDelete.name, function(err,results){
    if(err){return console.log(err)}
})

});
```

I think that number of passing arguments could be a problem. But how can I fix that when I want to use two parameters to find a record to delete?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right syntax of connection.query? What module are you using?

Comment: I use most common node js mysql connection -> https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: Thanks! Now it was easy to check the syntax of the command :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is wrong. It should be:

`...[toDelete.id, toDelete.name]...`

The values should be passed as array not as arguments.

Comment: Awesome! :)) Can you mark the answer as the correct one. It's a practice here in stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Done! :)